How to access DOM elements and use in function
Consider this code:
<script>
    let input;
    const foo = () => {
        let html = input.innerHTML;
        // Do something with HTML
    }
</script>

<button on:click={foo}>Foo</button>
{#if edit}
    <div bind:this={input}></div>
{/if}

I need to get the DOM Element for the div. Then use it in a function run by the button. How can I do this? bind:this only works in onMount, but I can't define foo inside onMount.
Understand that innerHTML or the specific method/property is not important. I just need the DOM element to use it in a function called when a button is pressed.

The element simply does not exist.
You have to wait for it to be created in the next update.
import { tick } from 'svelte';
async function foo() {
  edit = true; // change #if condition so next update creates element
  await tick();
  // [interact with bound element]
}

REPL

This does not work, input remains undefined event after await tick()

Yes, it does.

Ok, made a quick change and you are right, it does. Thank you. However, if await tick() is not right before accessing the element it doesn't work, like here. Any idea why this is?

Because the #if condition did not change. tick waits for the next update Svelte performs - nothing changed => no update necessary.

Ok, makes sense. But why would 'input' still be undefined here? The component has clearly mounted by the time of the button press. Shouldn't the element be assigned once it mounts? I understand using onMount for something that needs to run as soon as possible, but this is a click event...

No, nothing inside #if exists until the condition is true, likewise everything gets destroyed again when the condition becomes false. (There are some situations where this is not ideal, in those, the element can be hidden using CSS instead.)

I see, that makes sense, of course. Can't bind an element that doesn't exist... Thank you very much.
